# Disable auto activate feature

Tags: 2007, feature, feature-activation

I have a really strange behaviour, I'm working with SharePoint 2007 and I have a feature web application scoped, and i don't want it automatically being activated on deploying the solution, but it still does although I set this properties to false:

```
ActivateOnDefault="FALSE" AutoActivateInCentralAdmin="FALSE"
```

Here is the full xml of the feature

```
<Feature Id="EDFD660C-34BA-4c73-9928-AC8255352D834" Title="Workflows" Description="Activates my workflows" ActivateOnDefault="FALSE" AutoActivateInCentralAdmin="FALSE" Scope="WebApplication" Version="1.0.1.0" Hidden="FALSE" DefaultResourceFile="core" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" ReceiverAssembly="sharepoint, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d27a514ec27d3231" ReceiverClass="sharepoint.WorkflowFeature">
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="elements.xml" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Anyone has any idea, why it is still activated after deployement?

Comment: Features are never deactivated when yiou retract/uninstall a WSP. Are you sure you tested from a clean state, where the feature had been deactivated prior to retract/uninstall the WSP, and then reinstall it?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this behaviour also, please deactivate the feature from site collection first, then retract/remove solution and reinstall, if at the time of retraction the feature is active and you install the feature again, the feature gets activated upon installation

Comment: I'm not sure if it will fix, i think i did this before and it was the same, but i'll retest later, now i have another issue which doesnt allow me to test

Answer (score 0):

In your visual studio solution ,go to properties by right click on solution or by F4....Set activate on default to false.
Then build and package solution, that wsp will work for you.

Comment: This may be true for SharePoint 2010+ solutions, but for SharePoint 2007 there was no such tooling like this for Visual Studio (aside from CKS Dev Tools, which didn't include the properties you describe, only packaging and deployment from VS2008).